# CreateSolidBrush using hex values of color

Tags: mfc, gdi+, brush

how shall I create brush in mfc application using CreateSolidBrush method with given any hex value for color.

Comment: MFC and GDI+ are different libraries. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

[CreateSolidBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183518.aspx) takes an argument of type [COLORREF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx). A `COLORREF` is an alias for a `DWORD`, so you *could* simply assign a value to it:

```cpp
COLORREF color = 0xFF00FF;
HBRUSH hbr = ::CreateSolidBrush( color );
```

Make sure to adhere to the documented contract:

> The high-order byte must be zero.

A safer alternative would be to use the [RGB macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162937.aspx) instead:

```cpp
COLORREF color = RGB( 0xFF, 0x0, 0xFF );
HBRUSH bhr = ::CreateSolidBrush( color );
```

The `RGB` macro ensures, that the resulting `COLORREF` value conforms to the required memory layout.

---

If you need to extract the individual color components from a `COLORREF` (or `DWORD`) argument, you can use the [GetRValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144923.aspx), [GetGValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144893.aspx), and [GetBValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144856.aspx) macros:

```cpp
DWORD dwCol = 0xFF00FF;
BYTE r = GetRValue( dwCol );
BYTE g = GetGValue( dwCol );
BYTE b = GetBValue( dwCol );
```

While this does work, it introduces architecture specific code. At that point you could simply use the initial `DWORD` in place of a `COLORREF` (as illustrated in my first paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

```
CBrush newBrush;
COLORREF color = 0xFF00FFFF;  
newBrush.CreateSolidBrush(color);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This violates the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449.aspx): *"The high-order byte must be zero."*

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

```
#define GET_RVAL(num) (num & 0xff0000) >> 16
#define GET_GVAL(num) (num & 0x00ff00) >> 8
#define GET_BVAL(num) (num & 0x0000ff)
```

create brush using

```
hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(COLORREF(RGB(GET_RVAL(0xbfbfbf), GET_GVAL(0xbfbfbf), GET_BVAL(0xebfbfbf))));
```

Comment: Sorry, no. If you feel the compelling need to write your own preprocessor macros, at least do it right. In this case: **Always** wrap the entire expression inside parentheses. Of course, re-inventing the wheel isn't very helpful anyway (see my answer).